# basic php on dropdowns + act on what is selected from dropdown

Tags: php

this bit of code creates a dropdown with a list of files in the directory that start with `test*`

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 

      $filename;

       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
```

Now onece a file is selected from the dropdown how do I display it else where on the page?

This is my attempt but it just shows the filename that was last stored in the variable `$filename`. so it is static. **How I make it dispay the `$filename` that was selected?**

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 

      $filename; // trying to make it global here

       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select> 

<?php

echo "<p>this is a test ".$filename."</p>";

?>
```

### **edit1**

this might be useful http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: If you want to display it right after the user selects it, you might want to do it in the browser using JavaScript, not on the server with PHP.

Comment: well you need to wrap your select in a form and submit it to get the value of the selected option in php (server side)

Comment: that's were I need more guidance on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
<?php
    // show the selected value
    if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
        echo $_GET['value'];
    }

    // a set of options
    $options = array(
        'option1', 'option2', 'option3'
    );

    // the selected option
    $selected = 'option2';
?>
<select id="select" onchange="getValue()">
    <option <?php if ($selected == '') echo 'selected' ?> value="" disabled>Select...</option>
    <?php
        foreach($options as $each) {

            printf(
                "<option %s value='%s'>%s</option>\n",
                $selected == $each ? 'selected' : '',
                $each,  $each
            );
        }
    ?>
</select>
<!-- With the use of JavaScript  -->
<script>
    // get the vlaue of dropdown
    function getValue() {
        // sample only
        window.location.href = 'test.php?value=' + document.getElementById('select').value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: nothing is displayed when I select any of the options.

Comment: tks got this to work, but had to change this `test.php` to be my filename.

Comment: jsut noted a couple of bug but will accept is set me on my way. tks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple with a form.

```
<?php
$currentFilename =  (isset($_POST["s1"]) && $_POST["s1"] !== "") ? $_POST["s1"] : false;

if ($currentFilename !== false) {
 // a file has been selected
 // check it carefully because it can be very dangerous !
}
?>
<form method="post">
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" <?php echo ($currentFilename === false) ? "selected" : "" ; ?>">-----</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       $sel = ($currentFilename !== false && $filename == $currentFilename) ? " selected " : "";
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "' " . $sel .">".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>
</select> 
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You really need to check the user input (file selected) before using it.

Comment: the dropdown works, it has the different files, but nothing is displayed when I select one of the options

Comment: well you have to click on the submit button, then the selected value is in `$currentFilename`. If you dont want to click on the button look at the change event https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/change to submit the form when option changed...